# How to build one query out of two?

Tags: mysql

I have two queries that perform well when I paste them in sql console of phpmyadmin:

First query:

```
SET @count=0,@msisdn=00385913586990,@delivered=0;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT tmp.msisdn,max(count) FROM (
        SELECT
        sent_messages.msisdn,
        @count := if(delivered = 0 and sent_messages.msisdn = @msisdn, @count+1, 0) as count,
        @msisdn := 00385913586990,
        @delivered := delivered
        FROM  `sent_messages`
        WHERE  `msisdn` LIKE  '00385913586990'
        AND  `type` =  'PAID' ) as tmp
        group by tmp.msisdn
        having max(count) >= 14
```

When I try to execute these queries inside my php code I get blank results.

Here is how I tried to bind them together:

```
SELECT tmp.msisdn,max(count) FROM (
            SELECT
            sent_messages.msisdn,@count := 0,@msisdn=00385913586990,@delivered=0,
            @count := if(delivered = 0 and sent_messages.msisdn = @msisdn, @count+1, 0) as count,
            @msisdn := 00385913586990,
            @delivered := delivered
            FROM  `sent_messages`
            WHERE  `msisdn` LIKE  '00385913586990'
            AND  `type` =  'PAID' ) as tmp
            group by tmp.msisdn
            having max(count) >= 14
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: you can create a procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the variables in a subquery that you simply cross join. This way they are initialized once. When you do it in the `SELECT` clause, they are set back everytime a row is read.

```
SELECT tmp.msisdn,max(count) FROM (
        SELECT
        sent_messages.msisdn,
        @count := if(delivered = 0 and sent_messages.msisdn = @msisdn, @count+1, 0) as count,
        @msisdn := 00385913586990,
        @delivered := delivered
        FROM  `sent_messages`
        , (SELECT @count := 0, @msisdn := '00385913586990', @delivered := 0) var_init_subquery_alias
        WHERE  `msisdn` LIKE  '00385913586990'
        AND  `type` =  'PAID' ) as tmp
        group by tmp.msisdn
        having max(count) >= 14
```

Comment: No, it returns empty result set even in sql console now. However I appreciate your help, just doesn't work

Comment: That's probably because I put `00385913586990` in quotes when initializing, but forgot it for every other place you don't do it. I did it because I assumed it's a string because of the leading zeros (which are ignored without quotes, as it's converted into a number). Please check that.

Comment: Great job! Thanks a lot :)